# Are the live games casted in real time or is there a 2 min delay?

Tags: dota-2

I was watching EG vs VG and one of the casters were saying that the crowd mad it obvious when one of the teams were Roshing.

I think that means that the casting was realtime on the screens and also on twitch.

Anyone knows the answer, please let me know :]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking if a particular game-related channel is aired in real time, which has nothing to do with the game, itself.

Comment: @Timelord64 I disagree because it's about a gaming _event_ and how it was organized. Altough the asker seems to assume that the screens and the stream have the same dealy. An assumption I disagree with.

Comment: @Timelord64 I also disagree. It's definitely a technical question about the game mechanics! We are not talking about some streaming sites with user defined settings causing the delay time. It's **ingame**-spectation and not a video stream. To be more exact, not a single image, but only data are transmitted. Anyway this is definitely **on-topic** because it's a game mechanic specialiced for so called *premium-tournaments*! All other tournaments and matchmaking-games *have* a 2 min delay to prevent abusing the spectation mode.

Comment: I really see way too often, that people vote to close a question for beeing *Off-Topic* even if they don't know the game. Thats really, really bad!

Comment: @OttoV.  I agree with you, i just want a clue and help and these people are just like nazzies closing down topics. pff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general all big events are completely live, i.e. every big tournament or many LAN tournaments in general, as it can be guaranteed that players cannot use a ghost to give them information (A ghost is somebody watching the stream and feeding relevant information to a player/team).

As this cannot be guaranteed in an online-tournament, those are nearly always fitted with a stream delay of several minutes.